# UICollectionView Reload Data Not Working to update CollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, uicollectionview, reloaddata

UPDATTE:

I did forget to mention that the CollectionView is in the right hand side of a Split View Controller, and on the left side, I have tableView.  When a row is selected, I pass a new FEED ADDRESS and have it run refreshFeed method on the right hand side.

I have a collection view which parses data from an XML.  When a certain button is pressed, I want it to clear out the CollectionView, and load in data from a different XML, both of which are located online.  I use ASIHTTPRequest and GDATAXML classes to help me pull this off.  Here is my code.  I can verify through logs that the NSMutableArray is cleared, and successfully populated with the different XML, but reloadData never happens, as cellForItem doesn't get called a 2nd time.  Where have I messed up?

```
@interface RightViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;

@end

@implementation RightViewController

@synthesize allEntries = _allEntries;
@synthesize feeds = _feeds;
@synthesize queue = _queue;
@synthesize webViewController = _webViewController;
@synthesize activity;
@synthesize webViewController2 = _webViewController2;



@synthesize nameit2;
@synthesize nowplaying;
@synthesize entryofmp3 = _entryofmp3;
@synthesize nameit;
@synthesize progress;
@synthesize lastSelection;
@synthesize backgroundTaskIdentifier, theurl;
@synthesize thetable, thepath, downloadlabel, receivedData, progressbutton;


-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [_allEntries count];
}
- (void)loadFirstTime {
       self.allEntries = [NSMutableArray array];

        self.queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];


    if (_feedAddress == nil) {
        _feedAddress = @"http://www.316apps.com/AIMAPPLETV/AIMSeries.xml";
    }
    self.feeds = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:_feedAddress,
                  nil];
    for (NSString *feed in _feeds) {
        NSLog(@"Running Fine");
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:feed];
        ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [request setDelegate:self];
        [_queue addOperation:request];
    }
    NSLog(@"Still Good");
    //[self.collectionView reloadData];


}
-(void)changeFeed {
    [_allEntries removeAllObjects];
    _feedAddress = @"http://www.316apps.com/AIMAPPLETV/AIMCON.xml";
    [self loadFirstTime];
   // self.queue = nil;
    //_request.delegate = nil;
 //   _request.delegate = nil;

  //  [_collectionView reloadData];
}
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  // [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"playMovies" sender:self];
     RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *wifiStreamAddress = entry.articleUrl;
    AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: wifiStreamAddress] ];
    AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    playerViewController.player = player;

    // Keep pointers to player and controller
    self.player = player;
    self.playerViewController = playerViewController;



    [self presentViewController: playerViewController animated: true completion: ^{
        [self.player play];
    }];


}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"playMovies"])
    {
        PlayMovies *userViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        //if you need to pass data to the next controller do it here
    }
}
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cvCell";

    CVCell *cell = (CVCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        [cell.theimage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:entry.articleImage] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon@2x.png"]];

    cell.theimage.adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused = YES;
    cell.theimage.clipsToBounds = false;




    return cell;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

    self.allEntries = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        [self loadFirstTime];

}
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

}

- (void)parseRss:(GDataXMLElement *)rootElement entries:(NSMutableArray *)entries {

    NSArray *channels = [rootElement elementsForName:@"channel"];
    for (GDataXMLElement *channel in channels) {

        NSString *blogTitle = [channel valueForChild:@"title"];

        NSArray *items = [channel elementsForName:@"item"];
        for (GDataXMLElement *item in items) {
            NSString *articleTitle = [item valueForChild:@"title"];
            NSString *articleUrl = [[[[item elementsForName: @"enclosure"] lastObject] attributeForName: @"url"] stringValue];
            NSString *articleDateString = [item valueForChild:@"pubDate"];
            NSString *picture = [[[[item elementsForName: @"itunes:image"] lastObject] attributeForName: @"href"] stringValue];
            NSDate *articleDate = [NSDate dateFromInternetDateTimeString:articleDateString formatHint:DateFormatHintRFC822];
            RSSEntry *entry = [[RSSEntry alloc] initWithBlogTitle:blogTitle
                                                      articleTitle:articleTitle
                                                        articleUrl:articleUrl
                                                       articleDate:articleDate
                                                      articleImage:picture];


            [entries addObject:entry];
            NSLog(@"%@", entries);
        }
    }
     [self.collectionView reloadData];
}

- (void)parseFeed:(GDataXMLElement *)rootElement entries:(NSMutableArray *)entries {

    if ([rootElement.name compare:@"rss"] == NSOrderedSame) {
        [self parseRss:rootElement entries:entries];
    } else if ([rootElement.name compare:@"feed"] == NSOrderedSame) {
       // [self parseAtom:rootElement entries:entries];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Unsupported root element: %@", rootElement.name);
    }
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
    NSLog(@"Request Finished");
    [_queue addOperationWithBlock:^{

        NSError *error;
        GDataXMLDocument *doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:[request responseData]
                                                               options:0 error:&error];
        if (doc == nil) {
            NSLog(@"Failed to parse %@", request.url);
        } else {

            NSMutableArray *entries = [NSMutableArray array];
            [self parseFeed:doc.rootElement entries:entries];

            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

                for (RSSEntry *entry in entries) {

                    int insertIdx = [_allEntries indexForInsertingObject:entry sortedUsingBlock:^(id a, id b) {
                        RSSEntry *entry1 = (RSSEntry *) a;
                        RSSEntry *entry2 = (RSSEntry *) b;
                        return [entry1.articleDate compare:entry2.articleDate];
                    }];
                                       [_allEntries insertObject:entry atIndex:insertIdx];


                }

            }];

        }
    }];

}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
    NSError *error = [request error];
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    [self loadFirstTime];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

SECOND UPDATE:

I'm slowly getting somewhere.  Think it was due to me not having a Segue set up.  I drug a segue from the Cell of the Left Side's TableView to the Collection View's View Controller and set up as ShowDetail, and named it.  Then in LeftViewController:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"doingIt" sender:self];

    }
}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"doingIt"])
    {

        self.rightViewController = [[RightViewController alloc] init];
                [self.rightViewController refresheyc];

        //if you need to pass data to the next controller do it here
    }
}
```

In the RightViewController I have:

```
-(void)refresheyc {
    NSLog(@"This Sucks");
    [self.allEntries removeAllObjects];
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
    self.allEntries = nil;
    self.queue = nil;
    self.allEntries = [NSMutableArray array];

    self.queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];




    self.feeds = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://www.316apps.com/AIMAPPLETV/AIMCON.xml",
                  nil];
    for (NSString *feed in _feeds) {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:feed];
        NSLog(@"URL%@", url);
        ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [request setDelegate:self];
        [_queue addOperation:request];
    }

}
```

The Cells in CollectionView immediately disappear, but after several seconds, they all come back just the same, not changing the XML at all, but I get this:

```
2016-01-09 14:37:31.542 AIM-TV[7965:522091] This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release.
 Stack:(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109fa6ff5 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010d45cdeb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109fa6f2d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010aa96341 _AssertAutolayoutOnMainThreadOnly + 79
    4   Foundation                          0x000000010a8f6d6e -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 31
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010c804eb8 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withAutomaticEngineOptimizationDisabledIfEngineExists:] + 58
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010c804854 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 646
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010c804ec1 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withAutomaticEngineOptimizationDisabledIfEngineExists:] + 67
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010c804589 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:] + 242
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010c80405d -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _initializeHostedLayoutEngine] + 649
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010c7f652a -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _initializeLayoutEngine] + 152
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010c7f652a -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _initializeLayoutEngine] + 152
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010c804e24 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _layoutEngineCreateIfNecessary] + 62
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010c7f732b -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _tryToAddConstraint:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 126
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010c7f75ef -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _addConstraint:] + 274
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010c7fd247 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _updateContentSizeConstraints] + 779
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010c806270 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraints] + 224
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010c80559b -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:] + 550
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010c805866 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:] + 198
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010c8054aa -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:] + 309
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010c805866 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:] + 198
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010c8054aa -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:] + 309
    22  UIKit                               0x000000010c804ec1 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withAutomaticEngineOptimizationDisabledIfEngineExists:] + 67
    23  UIKit                               0x000000010c80583a -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:forSecondPass:] + 154
    24  UIKit                               0x000000010c805e9e __60-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraintsIfNeeded]_block_invoke + 98
    25  UIKit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't update UI elements in a background thread.  [self.collectionView reloadData] is called from parseRss which is itself called form parseFeed which is called by an operation on _queue.  if _queue doesn't happen to be processed by the main thread, you will get unpredictable results in the collectionView and more likely crashes.

You should dispatch your call to [self.collectionView reloadData] to the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { self.collectionView.reloadData() })
```

(this is the Swift syntax, i'm not familiar with Obj-C, sorry)

Answer (score 4):

Issue is really weird but it somehow works for me like, i added the update constraint code in the animation block,

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {() -> Void in

    //update constraints here

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded() 
    self.collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()

})

self.collectionView.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in *Alain's answer*, it is because UI changes need to be handled by the **main thread**. I see the question was posted using Objective C and answered in Swift so thought i'd post the **Objective C** version in case anyone needs it.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides what @Alain T. mentions wrt dspatching the call to reloadData(), make sure your item height is set appropriately. When itemHeight is zero or some very large value, you might see the 
`collectionView(numberOfItemsInSection) and numberOfSections()` 
called as expected but not your
`collectionView( cellForItemAt)`.

So make sure you have item height set with a call to:

```
collectionView(collectionView, layout, sizeForItemAt)
```